# Magento 2 (2.3) Rest API doesn't work with parameters

Tags: rest, api, parameters, magento2

I'm trying to retrieve several commands via the Magento 2 API. However, the returned result is either null or Error : "The signatire is invalid. Verify and try again." With this code :
[image: This is my code]

Yet when I search for an order by its entity_id it works perfectly:
[image: with this url]
[image]

I even tried to recover all the orders with:
[image]

And I get the following answer:
[image]

Is this an error on my part?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2016-10-11T04:00:00.0000000Z&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=from&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=2016-10-12T03:59:00.0000000Z&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=to&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[pageSize]=100
```

Comment: The result is the same, return null

Comment: can you please check that created_at value? change that based on your date and check.